# How to click on last image match in Sikulix

Tags: java, selenium, sikuli-x

I am automating a Java application using sikuli in our selenium automation project. In the Java application it displays a row of elements. Once I click the add button next to this row another row opens with the same fields. So now I have 2 rows with 2 identical images. Now once I add a second row, I want to click an element from the second row. This element would be the last identical element.

So how can I click this last element by using sikuli.

Comment: It might help if you could provide some code showing what you have tried. For example, do you have code that show how _you_ would do to click on the _first_ match?

Comment: Mind explaining a little more in detail? You have 2 identical images but you want to click an element from the second row of the second image? There's a click([image]) that you can take a screenshot of that image and click in that specific location.

Comment: Have a look at the Region features below(), right(), left(), ... to restrict the search region to the second row with respect to the first row (the match is the region).

Comment: As suggested by Raiman tried left() with another object, And it worked like charm. Thank you @Raiman.